# Making anchor(<a>) link not selected more than once in php

Tags: anchor

I want my anchor element link not be selected more than once, but unfortunately I can't. Please tell me if any ways to do so.

My tags are like this.
">Link
">Link

What I want here is that the link redirects to FirstThing.php and after doing something it come to the original form, but I need only SecondThing.php do something SecondThing.php and hide or not do any thing...please guys I need a quick solution.

Comment: tell the server it was clicked, then don't output the link the next time the page is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Unbind the click using jquery.

```
$('#my-selector').bind('click', function() {
       $(this).unbind('click');
       alert('Clicked and unbound!');
  });
```

This will disable the click after one click.

Demo 
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9r4avp1p/)

Answer (score 0):

The code below will intercept the future clicks of the anchor link after the initial click and prevent the link from being followed.

```
<a href="#" onclick="this.onclick = function() { return false; };">link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the href from the link immediately following a click event.

`<a href="#SomeAction" onclick="setTimeout(function() { this.removeAttribute('href'); }.bind(this), 0);">My Link</a>`

Comment: This can be work in a single form...but I need something differ. The link do something in the given reference page and redirect to the same page, but then it should not do something or hide from the form.